# IE11 cross domain popup window

Tags: postmessage

I want to send messages from a popup window created by window.open('domainB.com') to a parent window at domainA.com in IE11. I read on the internet that this is basically not possible in IE11, but I think the google sign in button does exactly this. Any idea how they do this?

All I want is from javascript on domainA.com, popup a window to domainB.com in IE11 and then have domainB.com send messages to domainA.com using postMessage, localstorage, cookies, anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/krakenjs/post-robot

this library does exactly what I was describing